# Should we have a flag for copied collections of answers to have them removed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

As there is no flag specifically targeting copied **answer** collections, or even simply duplicate answers, it isn't clear to me whether copied collections of answers are something we should or could flag for moderation.

Should a flag be added to cover this scenario?

Case in point:

- [**How to find my Subversion server version number?** - *Let's merge these responses…*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502906/193617)

**Example**

In the answer given above, the user has collected a number of other answers together, at a point in time and attracted upvotes and reputation for it while adding no appreciable value.

In fact, because the answer collection was copied at a point in time, some of the collected answers are no longer up-to-date. The original answers belong to their authors and some were edited by the author to address comment responses.

**Reasons to remove answer collections**

1. *They add no value.*

   Their sole purpose is possibly to address something that should be a Design or User Experience improvement to the entire Stackexchange network.
2. *They break the link between authors and their work.*

   The author of the copied work, who has the knowledge to begin with, should not need to maintain their original answer along with the copy in the answer collection. If the original answer needs to be updated due to changed technologies or to correct an error, the copied answer collection becomes stale.
3. *They break the Stack Exchange answer ranking system.*

   People who read these collections are not upvoting the source answer. They're upvoting the collection, which stops the good answers from rising to the top. Instead the collection, with good, less helpful and sometimes bad answers, rises in rank.
4. *They prevent answer authors gaining deserved reputation.*

   The original author of each answer gains none of the deserved reputation from upvotes to a copied answer collection.

Comment: Your title doesn't quite match your question. Are you asking "should i flag these" or "should there be a specific flag option for this scenario"

Comment: @psubsee2003 this is reflected by the tags: "should I flag these" -> [discussion], "should there be a specific flag option for this scenario" -> [feature-request]

Comment: My view of this issue is that these answers are trying to take the place of the new Documentation feature (by creating answer anthologies). However, lacking the voting, attribution, etc. that is supported in the Documentation section, these answers contribute nothing.

Comment: You can already flag almost anything for moderator attention. Why not doing this? Checking if an answer really is just a useless combination of other answers **or** adds something new and gives proper attribution therefore being a valid answer is surely not a very simple task.

Comment: I've seen plenty of Duplicate Questions moderated, but as there's no specific flag for these duplicate answers, particularly answer collections, it doesn't seem clear that those are either discouraged or able to be flagged for moderation.

Comment: @Trilarion Adding something and giving attribution should be done as an edit to an existing answer in my opinion. It doesn't seem valid to copy something into a collection, even if you're adding attribution and/or adding something new. If there really is a new answer, add it on its own, not in some collection along with other answers copied in with attribution.

Comment: @Christopher we can debate whether collections are useful or not, but in general if you have something to add to an existing answer, you should not edit the answer, but instead write your own answer and attribute the original answer. That is a long standing community consensus

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks for clearing that up. You know thinking about that, it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr;**

There is no single way to evaluate these types of posts, they need to be judged on a case-by-base basis.  They should be judged based on whether there is strong evidence of plagiarism and whether the combined answer provides additional value beyond just combining the answers for the sake of combining them. Other factors like "reputation" should be secondary to evaluating the posts but if properly attributed, you would hope that someone upvoted the compilation answer would also upvote the individual answers.

In the case of your example, there is virtually no attribution, so that would fall afoul of these guidelines and it should be flagged or at least edited to include attribution, depending on its value

---

To add my 2 cents to the discussion on whether or not these types of issues should be flagged, my opinion is **it depends**.  There are 2 components to this, **attribution** and **value**.  You have indicated these have no value, but I don't think you can make a blanket statement like that on all cases of these answers.

First of all, answers should never be copied without attribution.  Anything else is essentially plagiarism, however, unless it is copied word for word, it is very difficult to identify an answer that was plagiarized vs 2 users who came up with similar answers independent of one another.

In this case, the "let's merge these responses together" phrase is a giant red flag to say that the user did indeed copied the answers.  It could possibly be debated that the "let's merge" phrase is attribution, but I don't think it goes nearly far enough.  The individual components of the answer should be linked to the individual answers that provided inspiration and the individual owners of the answers should be identified by name (and technically by the attribution rules of the site, there should be a link to the users profile, although this piece tends to be lightly enforced for internal sources within SO and only expected for content copied to external sources or other SE sites).

The other piece of this is the value such an answer provided. It is commonly accepted that if you have something to add to an existing answer, you should provide your own answer and expand on the other answer (properly attributed of course).  In this case, the new answer provides additional value beyond the original answer, so it is perfectly acceptable.

Now what if you have something to add to multiple answers?  Should you leave multiple new answers expanding on each one individually?  Or should you just provide a single answer and copy and attribute all of the answers in one post.  That probably depends on how related your additional content is.  If it is the same "additional content" applied to different answers then a single combined answer is probably appropriate.  But if each answer has different "additional content", then separate answers are probably more appropriate, but I wouldn't delete something just because it was combined.

One additional consideration is if you have a very cluttered answers (with dozens of responses of varying quality), especially if the post is a canonical post intended to address a commonly asked question, then pulling together specific highlights into a single answer would provide some value.

In this specific case, the user appears to have combined answers to provide different ways to get the appropriate information via different methods.  I'm not in a position to judge this specific case you identified as I'm not sure how valuable having all of the different access methods together is but frankly if the various answers are all equally correct and the only different is simply which protocal is used to access, then the value of "ranking" them via different answers is immaterial since there is no "right" or "wrong".

---

And to address the feature request in your title "Should we have a flag for copied collections of answers to have them removed?"

**My response is absolutely not.**

Flags are intended to convey *general* issues or identify problems that need to be addressed *immediately*.  A compilation answer falls into neither case.  It is a very specific (and rare) occurrence, and does not warrant immediate removal.  If we had specific flags for every individual type of problem, the flag dialog would be so large, it would be virtually unusable.

The type of flag also dictates who sees the flagged post.  Many of the general flag types actually end up in review queues for the community to review, and do not go only to moderators.

For cases in which do not fit any of the general cases or if the issue specifically needs an elected-moderator to address, the appropriate thing to do is use a custom flag (select `flag > other`) and provide a brief but complete explanation of the problem **and** what action you expect the moderators to take.

So if you find one of these answers that you think fails to add value or is heavily plagiarized, then just use a custom flag.  Be sure to explain why, and might be helpful to link to the specific answers that were copied as well.

Comment: Very balanced and thoughtful answer. It's basically a weakness of the Q&A model used here that every A is a single entity and there is not much collaboration going on as compared to Documentation or Wikipedia for example. But on the other hand it also simplifies matters quite a lot and has been proven quite effective. It just may result in multiple solutions each one with problems instead of one canonical perfect one. That's inherent.